# Android Google map not loading properly

Tags: android, google-maps

[image][image]    ![package com.example.mytt.cardguide;

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.example.mytt.R;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class CardGuide_MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnShowLocation;
    // GPSTracker class
    GPSTracker gps;
    GoogleMap map;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.cardguide);


        // Get a handle to the Map Fragment
        final GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();


         Button btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showlocation_btn);

        // show location button click event
            btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {        
                    // create class object
                    gps = new GPSTracker(CardGuide_MainActivity.this);

                    // check if GPS enabled     
                    if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                        double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                        double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                          LatLng mylocation = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);

                          String strAdd = "";
                          Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(CardGuide_MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
                          try {
                              List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                              if (addresses != null) {
                                  Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                                  StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("");

                                  for (int i = 0; i < returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                                      strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                                  }
                                  strAdd = strReturnedAddress.toString();
                                  Log.w("My Current loction address", "" + strReturnedAddress.toString());
                              } else {
                                  Log.w("My Current loction address", "No Address returned!");
                              }
                          } catch (Exception e) {
                              e.printStackTrace();
                              Log.w("My Current loction address", "Canont get Address!");
                          }



                        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mylocation, 13));
                      Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                      .position(mylocation)
                      .title(""+strAdd+""));

                      marker.showInfoWindow();


                        // \n is for new line
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                    }else{
                        // can't get location
                        // GPS or Network is not enabled
                        // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                        gps.showSettingsAlert();
                    }

                }
            });



    }
    }][3]
```

as i Click on Image view the map loads as it should, but after clicking on Show my Location Button the map disappears but the address of the current location comes as it should.

I dont know why the map disappears after clicking on button.

I even checked the map object that is also not null...

Answer (score 0):

There was an mismatch in API key and package name on Google API console.